# Typescript classe how specify that element can be optional

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose to have this Interface:
Employee.model.ts:

```
interface EmployeeInterface{
    name: string;
    salary?: number;
    date: Date;
}
```

I know how I can do :

```
export class Employee implements EmployeeInterface{
    public name: string;
    public salary: number;
    public date: Date;
}
```

My question is how I specify in the constructor that salary parameters can be or not canno't be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define the fields as parameter constructors (by adding a visibility modifier to the parameter) and mark the apropriate field and parameter as optional (but you will need to put it at the end of the parameter list):

```
interface ObjectToSellInterface{
  name: string;
  salary?: number;
  date: Date;
}
export class ObjectToSell implements ObjectToSellInterface{
  public constructor(
    public name: string,
    public date: Date, 
    public salary?: number){ }
}
```

The above code would be equivalent to:

```
export class ObjectToSell implements ObjectToSellInterface{

  public name: string;
  public date: Date;
  public salary?: number;

  public constructor(
    name: string,
    date: Date, 
    salary?: number){ 
      this.date = date;
      this.name = name;
      this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Doflamingo19 depends what you are trying to do. Private fields can't be part of an interface implementation. If you are thinking of using private fiedls and creating public get/set properties, don't! it's not a common JS/TS practice. You can change the field  to a property later if needed.

Comment: @Doflamingo19 you can use them, but there is no point in using them if all you re going to do is return a private field/set the private field when the property is set.